# several on a null object reference error in kotlin after updated to the latest version of android studio and kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function in a class(CustomCalendar.kt) and i was using that function of CustomCalendar for a month but in these 2 days i am getting different errors from that. so this error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewTreeObserver android.widget.ScrollView.getViewTreeObserver()' on a null object
```

and this is my makeCurrentMonth function of CustomCalendar class

```
fun makeCurrentMonth(context: Context, view: View, activity: Activity) {
        val resources: Resources = activity.resources
        for (i in 1..maxDaysOfMonth) {

            val roundDay = GregorianCalendar(year, month, i)
            val dayOfWeek = roundDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
            val dayOfMonth = roundDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

//          ------------------1 to 9 number of day in month---------------------------------
            if (dayOfMonth in 1..9) {
                val add0 = "0$i".toInt()
                val dayText = choosingDayOfWeek(dayOfWeek) + "\n0$dayOfMonth"
                val dayViewId =
                    resources.getIdentifier("day_0$i", "id", context.packageName)
                Log.d("TAG", i.toString())
                view.findViewById<TextView>(dayViewId).text = dayText


//              -----------------current day-------------------------
                if (i == day) {
                view.radio_group.check(choosingToday(add0))
                val dayID = view.findViewById<TextView>(dayViewId)
                view.scroll_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
                    view.scroll_view.post {
                        view.scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(
                            dayID.left - 35,
                            0
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

//          -------------11 to 31 one day of month---------------------
            else {
                val dayText = choosingDayOfWeek(dayOfWeek) + "\n$dayOfMonth"
                val dayViewId =
                    resources.getIdentifier("day_$i", "id", context.packageName)
                Log.d("TAG", i.toString())
                view.findViewById<TextView>(dayViewId).text = dayText

//              ------------------current day ---------------------------
                if (i == day) {
                    view.radio_group.check(choosingToday(i))
                    val dayID = view.findViewById<TextView>(dayViewId)
                    view.scroll_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
                        view.scroll_view.post {
                            view.scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(
                                dayID.left - 35,
                                0
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is my variables in class

```
private val c = Calendar.getInstance()

private val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
private val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
private val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
private val currentDay = GregorianCalendar(year, month, day )

private val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
private val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
private val maxDaysOfMonth = currentDay.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
```

radio_buttons_month.xml

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_height="100dp">


    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingHorizontal="16dp">


        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/day_01"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/days_radio_button"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="15dp"
            android:text="@string/_01"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_days" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/day_02"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/days_radio_button"
            android:button="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_semibold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="15dp"
            android:text="@string/_02"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_days" />

// and other radio buttons...

    </RadioGroup>


</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and Im using this function in my fragments and had no problem and didnt change code that affect this line(at least I know) just updated kotlin and also updated android studio to 4.2.2

Comment: on which line does the error occur?

Comment: Can you show your resources view layout related please ?

Comment: @ChocolateChapta view.scroll_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
                    view.scroll_view.post {
                        view.scroll_view.smoothScrollTo(
                            dayID.left - 35,
                            0
                            )
                        }

Comment: @crazy4dev I added the layout

Comment: @Morteza So probably `view.scroll_view.post`  returns `null`. Maybe check if its null before running this line. `if (view.scroll_view.post != null)`

Comment: @ChocolateChapta but i didnt change anything and this code was working for a month. and idk about your solve way but it seems view.scroll_view is always null and this is not a solve, just like deleting that part of code

Comment: @Morteza it's not a solution, it's a test whether it would work that way. Where in your code is `view.scroll_view` assigned?

Comment: @ChocolateChapta you were right, I commented the related part and then it gives me another error in my fragment not this class and ##val radioButton = view.findViewById(selectedId) as RadioButton## this is the line debuger is showing me now

Comment: @ChocolateChapta and i have to say i had a copy of my project but didnt upgrade to the latest version in that and i tested that and it worked okay, without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take a reference of your view first, I see in your code that you call viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener,

**view.scroll_view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener** or this error say that your scroll_view is null.

To avoid this, I think you have to take a reference of your view first, it make your code more clean and readable also.

**Here is an exemple:**

```kotlin
//If you use fragment
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
   HorizontalScrollView scroll_view= (HorizontalScrollView ) view.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
```

The exemple above is the most sure way (I think because it still work in the newer version of kotlin) to bind a view using the view id.

But, [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#:%7E:text=View%20binding%20is%20a%20feature,file%20present%20in%20that%20module.) also explain the step you have to follow in order to bind a view in the new version of kotlin.

Comment: The link above show you how to bind a view in the newest version of kotlin, please take a look at this.

Comment: so as you said, in newest version kotlin has some changes and i had to use binding method (or that findViewById ) for finding the ids from now